# Change a svg path when another element is hover

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm posting my first question because I have an average level with web languages and I don't know all the subtleties. I don't know if I should touch the CSS which was my first idea or if I should do Javascript but I don't know enough about it...
I want to change the zones of a map in an svg file when I hover over another element on the page. I'm already trying to change the fill of the .maptest class when I hover over the "chateauneufbeta" class. What I'm trying to do is below : /*What I want to do : when the class chateauneufbeta is hovered over it changes the path of the .maptest class*/

My map area has two classes: .ZoneVerte and .maptest for more freedom of selection.

I translated a part of my CSS to help you (I am of French origin ^^)

I use Wordpress for information.
Here is a part of my current CSS and HTML:

```css
/*Affichage flex de la carte */
.location__map-region{
display: flex;
margin: 2rem auto;
}

/*Séparation de chaque région avec une ligne blanche de 1 pixel */
.location__map-region path {
stroke: #ffffff;
stroke-width: 1; 
transition: .6s fill;
}

/*What I want to do : when the class chateauneufbeta is hovered over it changes the path of the .maptest class*/
.chateauneufbeta:hover ~ .maptest {
fill: #93c020!important;
opacity: 1.0!important;
}

/*Normal colour of the Châteauneuf territory*/
.ZoneVerte{
fill: #93c020;
opacity: 0.8;
}

/*Colour of the Châteauneuf area when it is flown over */
.ZoneVerte:hover{
fill: #93c020;
opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Part of my HTML code with the list of cities on the side (see the image at the bottom of the post):

```html
<div class="location__wrapper"><div class="location__content"><ul class="location__list">
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="1" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.antibes-juanlespins.com/">Antibes Juan-les-Pins</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="22" class="location__list-link" href="http://bezaudun.fr/">Bézaudun-les-Alpes</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="3" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.biot.fr/">Biot</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="21" class="location__list-link" href="https://bouyon.fr/">Bouyon</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="15" class="location__list-link" href="http://www.caussols.fr/fr/">Caussols</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item chateauneufalpha"><a data-area-id="9" class="location__list-link chateauneufbeta" href="https://www.ville-chateauneuf.fr/">Châteauneuf</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="18" class="location__list-link" href="http://www.cipieres.fr/">Cipières</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="19" class="location__list-link" href="#">Conségudes</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="14" class="location__list-link" href="http://www.courmes.fr/">Courmes</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="17" class="location__list-link" href="#">Coursegoules</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="13" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.gourdon06.fr/fr">Gourdon</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="16" class="location__list-link" href="http://www.greolieres.fr/">Gréolières</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="6" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.lacollesurloup.fr/fr">La Colle-sur-Loup</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="20" class="location__list-link" href="https://laroqueenprovence.fr/">La Roque-en-Provence</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="12" class="location__list-link" href="https://lebarsurloup.fr/">Le Bar-sur-Loup</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="10" class="location__list-link" href="https://lerouret.fr/">Le Rouret</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="24" class="location__list-link" href="#">Les Ferres</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="8" class="location__list-link" href="https://mairie-opio.fr/">Opio</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="7" class="location__list-link" href=" https://www.ville-roquefort-les-pins.fr/">Roquefort-les-Pins</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="5" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.saint-pauldevence.com/">Saint-Paul de Vence</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="11" class="location__list-link" href="https://tourrettessurloup.com/">Tourrettes-sur-Loup</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="2" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.ville-valbonne.fr/">Valbonne Sophia Antipolis</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="23" class="location__list-link" href="http://www.vallauris-golfe-juan.fr/">Vallauris Golfe-Juan</a></li>
<li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="4" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.villeneuveloubet.fr/">Villeneuve-Loubet</a></li></ul></div>
```

The result I expect at the end is the following:

[map change color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS20L.png)

Comment: CSS only adds styles to HTML elements. You have to use JavaScript to dynamically change the behavior and add/remove styles accordingly.

Comment: Even if I have the class of my text to be hovered over and the class of my area to change colour when the text in question is hovered over? @Nat

Comment: Your example code only includes CSS. Please edit it to be a proper [mcve]

Comment: that works if you want to change styles in the SAME element that you are hovering. If you want to change styles in a child/sibling element you could use [CSS Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) but it becomes DOM tree dependence and very complicated if the element that you hover is not close to the element you want to select

Comment: Do you actually want to change a path or are you just wanting to change an area's color?

Comment: I changed my question to be more precise and translated part of my CSS. However, my HTML for the map is too big to fit in the post. I could only put the one for the list of cities (on the left on the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some simple code that shows how to do what you want.  I've added comments to the code to describe what each step is doing.

```js
// Find all the <a> elements in the list
var items = document.querySelectorAll("UL.location__list LI A");

// To each of them, add an event handler for when the mouse enters its box, and also when it leaves
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", itemMouseOver);
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", itemMouseOut);
});

function itemMouseOver(evt) {
  // Get the value of the data-area-id attribute for the <a> we are entering
  var areaId = evt.target.dataset['areaId'];
  // Use it to find the right circle, and add the class "active" to its class attaribute
  document.getElementById(areaId).classList.add("active");
}

function itemMouseOut(evt) {
  // Get the value of the data-area-id attribute for the <a> we are entering
  var areaId = evt.target.dataset['areaId'];
  // Use it to find the right circle, and remove the class "active" from its class attaribute
  document.getElementById(areaId).classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
/* The default style for a circle */
svg circle {
  fill: lightgreen;
}

/* the style for when the circle is hovered */
svg circle.active {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="location__wrapper">
  <div class="location__content">
    <ul class="location__list">
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="1" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.antibes-juanlespins.com/">Antibes Juan-les-Pins</a></li>
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="22" class="location__list-link" href="http://bezaudun.fr/">Bézaudun-les-Alpes</a></li>
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="3" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.biot.fr/">Biot</a></li>
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="21" class="location__list-link" href="https://bouyon.fr/">Bouyon</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle id="1" cx="25" cy="25" r="20"/>
  <circle id="22" cx="75" cy="25" r="20"/>
  <circle id="3" cx="25" cy="75" r="20"/>
  <circle id="21" cx="75" cy="75" r="20"/>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Both directions:

```js
// Find all the <a> elements in the list
var items = document.querySelectorAll("UL.location__list LI A");

// To each of them, add an event handler for when the mouse enters its box, and also when it leaves
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", itemMouseOver);
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", itemMouseOut);
});

function itemMouseOver(evt) {
  // Get the value of the data-area-id attribute for the <a> we are entering
  var areaId = evt.target.dataset['areaId'];
  // Use it to find the right circle, and add the class "active" to its class attribute
  document.getElementById(areaId).classList.add("active");
}

function itemMouseOut(evt) {
  // Get the value of the data-area-id attribute for the <a> we are entering
  var areaId = evt.target.dataset['areaId'];
  // Use it to find the right circle, and remove the class "active" from its class attribute
  document.getElementById(areaId).classList.remove("active");
}



// Find all the <circle> elements in the list
var circles = document.querySelectorAll("svg circle");

// To each of them, add an event handler for when the mouse enters its box, and also when it leaves
circles.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", circleMouseOver);
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", circleMouseOut);
});

function circleMouseOver(evt) {
  // Get the id of the circle
  var areaId = evt.target.id;
  // Use it to find the right list item, the one with data-area-id="<id>", and add the class "active" to its class attribute
  document.querySelector('.location__list-item a[data-area-id="'+areaId+'"]').parentElement.classList.add("active");
}

function circleMouseOut(evt) {
  // Get the id of the circle
  var areaId = evt.target.id;
  // Use it to find the right list item, the one with data-area-id="<id>", and remove the class "active" from its class attribute
  document.querySelector('.location__list-item a[data-area-id="'+areaId+'"]').parentElement.classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
.location__list-item:hover,
.location__list-item.active
{
  background-color: green;
}


/* The default style for a circle */
svg circle {
  fill: lightgreen;
}

/* the style for when the circle is hovered */
svg circle:hover,
svg circle.active {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="location__wrapper">
  <div class="location__content">
    <ul class="location__list">
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="1" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.antibes-juanlespins.com/">Antibes Juan-les-Pins</a></li>
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="22" class="location__list-link" href="http://bezaudun.fr/">Bézaudun-les-Alpes</a></li>
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="3" class="location__list-link" href="https://www.biot.fr/">Biot</a></li>
      <li class="location__list-item"><a data-area-id="21" class="location__list-link" href="https://bouyon.fr/">Bouyon</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle id="1" cx="25" cy="25" r="20"/>
  <circle id="22" cx="75" cy="25" r="20"/>
  <circle id="3" cx="25" cy="75" r="20"/>
  <circle id="21" cx="75" cy="75" r="20"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul LeBeau. It's very helpful. I'll have to think about reversing that. When I hover over a circle it changes the style of the text. I'll try that and if I can't do it I'll come back here.

Comment: Your qiuestion said you wanted it the other way round. But anyway, good luck!

Comment: Yes I know but in fact I would like to do both ideally. One change when the city is overflown and another when the city's territory is overflown. So you were good but I'll look for it to apply both ways ;)

Comment: Well, I must be an idiot, but I can't do the same thing the other way round: when I hover the mouse over the map it must transform the city text (on the left).
@Paul LeBeau

Comment: It's pretty much the same. It's just a little bit trickier getting back from the `id` to the correct `data-area-id`. But not too bad.  I've added a new example with both directions working.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll try this right away :)

Comment: What if the second part of the script should affect the class "location__list-link" and not "location__list-item"? My css rules are based on this.

I can't seem to use the right selector in JS...

Comment: It should just be `querySelectorAll(".location__list-link")`

Comment: I want to use the same principle but assign the class "location__list-link".
So by replacing here ?
document.querySelector('.location__list-item a[data-area-id="'+areaId+'"]').parentElement.classList.remove("active");

Comment: Re your recent question *What if ...(it)... should affect the class "location__list-link" and not "location__list-item"?*. It's not affecting `location__list-item`. It's affecting `location__list-item a`.  Which is the same as `location__list-link`.  But if you want to target the `<a>` directly, you can change it to `document.querySelector('.location__list-link[data-area-id="'+areaId+'"]').parentElement.classList.remove("active");` if you like