# Accessing SVG <path> element`s with use Efffect

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-hooks

I am currently working on a svg map. I have been trying to get the location the user is hovering on based on the title provided by the SVG Path as shown below:

```
<svg viewBox="0.288 -24.265 791.9 521.477" width="791.9" height="521.477">
   <path
       className="estados"
       d="m 390.52786,309.79244 -2.34,-2.26 -0.07,-1.21 1.24,-2.87 3.33,-4.59 0.93,-3.24 
       1.07,-0.73 1.79,-0.38 3.47,-1.97 1.21,-0.92 0.39,-1.26 0.73,-0.17 0.77,1.39 
       1.33,1.34 4.44,2.63 0.59,2.44 1.14,2.04 0,0 0.26,0.59 -0.24,1.6 1.96,2.14 
       -4.28,1.97 -2.55,3.55 -0.72,0.5 -3.02,1.04 -1.26,0.06 -2.17,-1.02 -1.74,-1.41 
       -4.21,-0.38 z"
       title="Aguascalientes"
       id="MX-AGU"
       fill="#66bfbf"
    ></path>
</svg>
```

To access the title I have tried the following with no luck:

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState("Selecciona tu destino");

  const handleMouseover = () => {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("title");

    setLocation(attribute);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("estados");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseover);
    }
  }, []);
```

In this example my expected var attribute = "Aguascalientes"  ( as it is the title attribute <path title="Aguascalientes" ...>)

But I am getting the following error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to solve the problem using the answer from this post [Change a svg path when another element is hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186067/change-a-svg-path-when-another-element-is-hover) with the following outcome code:

```
function itemMouseOver(evt) {
    setLocation(evt.target.attributes["title"].value);
  }

  function itemMouseOut(evt) {
    setLocation("Selecciona tu destino");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("path.estados");

    items.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("mouseover", itemMouseOver);
      item.addEventListener("mouseout", itemMouseOut);
    });
  });
```